# angular bootstrap html popover not being displayed

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the uib-popover-html directive and it doesn't display. If I use the uib-popover or uib-popover-template directive it displays correctly. Am I missing something?

This works

```
$scope.dynamicPopover = {
    content: 'Hello, World!',
    templateUrl: 'app/login/popover.html',
    title: 'Title'
};


<!-- popover.html -->
<div>
  <b style="color: red">I can</b> have <div class="label label-success">HTML</div> content
</div>
<!-- /popover.html -->

<button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>

<button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>
```

This doesn't

```
<button uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" class="btn btn-default">HTML Popover</button>
```

Comment: what is "htmlPopover" as used in your uib-popover-html directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $sce (Strict Contextual Escaping) to show that the HTML is safe:

```
$htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>Popover Content</div>');
```

This feature exists to avoid user's from inputting HTML that could be nefarious into a form, etc.

References: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce